# Best way to store messages in memory

Tags: node.js

I am using socket.io in node.js I have to store every chat message in ram for 10 seconds.Then I will save to database them and I will delete them from ram.What is the best way to this ? What should I use ?

Data structre:

```
User1->message1,message2,message3,message4...
User2->message1,message2,message3,message4...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an array to store chat messages in memory. The V8 Node.js heap memory has ~1.5GB limit though, so if you have a ton of messages to store for those 10 seconds, I would recommend buffering them in a dedicated in-memory data store like Redis.

```
var messages = [];
messages.push(message);
```

Comment: It can be up to 10k mesaages in memory.I think redis best for me.What do you think ?

Comment: Redis would be fine for 10k messages in memory.